# Find a file using PowerShell and get the folder it is in

Tags: powershell

Im trying to search for a file in my HDD using this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter *.pst -Recurse | ?{$_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName
```

This should return the folder it is in. There might be more than one so I would need to store it in a array. It returns a Access denied error.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Add `-erroraction SilentlyContinue` to the `Get-ChildItem` parameters list. This way your cmdlet won't stop at the very first access denied error and only scan those folders where you have access.

Comment: Downvoted because the main issue is how to put these in a array, erroractions are secundary.

Comment: @riahc3, Getting Access denied and receiving nothing in the result, is because one of the folders that's checked is `System Volume Information` which does not have ACEs for users to read. And since `Get-ChildItem` stops at access denied errors, the proper way to overcome these errors is instruct the cmdlet to ignore the traversal access denied errors via `-erroraction`. Storing in array is simple, you assign the result to a variable, `$var=Get-ChildItem....`. XY problem detected.

Answer (score -1):

The filter `?{$_.PSIsContainer}` will match only objects that are containers (i.e. directories), but your `Get-ChildItem` statement produces only files, not directories, so the end result of your pipeline will be empty.

You're looking for the `Directory` property of the matching files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter '*.pst' -Recurse |
  Select-Object -Expand Directory -Unique |
  Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

The "access denied" error you're getting is because you traverse the entire volume `C:`, which is very likely to contain several folders you don't have access to (not even as an administrator).

As [@Vesper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31310207/1630171) already suggested, add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Get-ChildItem` statement (or set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`) to make the statement skip over directories you can't access.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter '*.pst' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Select-Object -Expand Directory -Unique |
  Select-Object -Expand FullName
```

If you want the containing folder for each matching file instead of just the unique paths remove the `-Unique` parameter from the first `Select-Object` statement.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: care to explain what you consider wrong with this answer?

Comment: I expect it's OP and he has a different problem than what's explained.